# Как передать переменную методом POST если я используя Header для редиректа?

Tags: php

У меня есть метод который перенаправляет на определенную страницу.

```
static public function redirect($url, $x) {
// $x - переменная которую нужно передать
header('Location: ' . self::root() . '/' . $url);
    exit();
}
```

У меня появилась необходимость передавать переменную методом POST. Подскажите как используя header() передать переменную методом POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак.
Header перезает заголовок **ответа**, а POST - это метод **запроса**.

Переменную передавать через сессию.